# MVC in a AWS Lambda .NET serverless application?

Tags: asp.net-core, aws-lambda, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm new to using AWS Lambda with .NET core. I'm a bit confused by the "Pages" directory that the boilerplate project is creating with the "code behind" cs files for each of the .cshtml files.

I was hoping to have the standard /Controllers and /Views folders and route though MVC controllers, but I'm not sure AWS Lambda will work in that fashion.

Do I have to use this /Pages structure with the code behind files in a AWS Lambda application?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working by including

```
[HttpGet]
```

On the controller methods. Also, there was an update with the AWS extension for visual studio for the release of .net core 2.1, so UPDATE if you have an older version.

The templates DO NOT include a .net core 2.1 MVC application, that would be a nice addition. I don't know many people using code-behind Razor pages and it's a weird choice to make that the default.